# How to stream only new data (newly appended) from old file in spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have multiple files that are written in chunks and I want my stream to process each files new data every time data is appended. Also I want my Stream to only read new files and not the already processed files.
Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible as a direct source.

1. Need to use Flume 'tail' approach and put that tail into HDFS
   directory as a file and let Spark Structured Streaming watch that
   directory.
2. Or you can use things like NIFI.